# Cannot read all texts in json format in parsing tweet?

Tags: python

I try to write python program to extract text in tweet in json file format (excluding retweet) with python. following is snippcode in python (file is large 20MB so it is not included here).

```
import sys
import difflib
import twitter
import json
from pprint import pprint

# Input argument is the filename of the JSON ascii file from the Twitter API

filename = sys.argv[1]
tweets_text = [] # We will store the text of every tweet in this list
tweets_location = [] # Location of every tweet (free text field - not always `enter code here`accurate or given)
tweets_timezone = [] # Timezone name of every tweet

# Loop over all lines
f = file(filename, "r")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    try: 
        tweet = json.loads(line)

        # Ignore retweets!
        if (tweet[1].has_key('retweeted_status') or not ( tweet[1].has_key('text'))): 
            continue

            # Fetch text from tweet
            text = tweet[1]['text'].encode('utf-8','ignore').lower()

            # Ignore 'manual' retweets, i.e. messages starting with RT      
            if text.find("RT ") > -1:
                continue

        tweets_text.append( text )
        tweets_location.append( tweet[1]['user']['location'].encode('utf-8','ignore') )
        tweets_timezone.append( tweet[1]['user']['time_zone'].encode('utf-8','ignore') )

    except ValueError:
        pass

# Show result
print tweets_text
```

The problem is that I get only one tweet. Could anyone point one the error?

Comment: Start by not catching the `ValueError` exception. You probably have JSON data spanning multiple lines of data.

Comment: I am sorry for format of question i my post. Could you pls help me how to correct this error. since when i use following codes that i got from other post : import json
    from pprint import pprint
    json_data=open('data.json')

    data = json.load(json_data)
    pprint(data)
i could see a lot of contents such as contributors, coordinates, id,.., text...

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the json file line by line and you're loading each line as if it is a valid JSON, which it probably isn't. Try something like:

```
    lines = f.readlines()
    tweet = json.loads(lines)
```

And from there you should be able to access all the JSON elements via tweet

EDIT:
Assuming your JSON has the same structure as returned by https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

you can do something like:

```
    f = file(filename,"r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    tweets_json = json.loads(lines[0])
    for tweet in tweets_json:
        if tweet['retweeted'] == False:
            tweets_text.append(tweet['text'])

    print tweets_text
```

Comment: Hi Radi. i could not get your advise since i have both command line in my code in question. pls more elaborate since directly use two command like these , i do not know how to go througgth all tweets to get contents

Comment: You are iterating over each line in your file. So if you have a long json the lines will wrap and when you pass each line to json.loads() it won't be valid json. Try passing the whole file to json.loads() and see if you get the correct structure. p.s. test it with small subset of the file not with the whole 20MB file.

Comment: Hi Radi. when i try import json
from pprint import pprint
json_data=open('json_data')

data = json.load(json_data)
pprint(data)
 i could see a lot of data. so in my code, i get line by line to see each tweet to extract the contents, but i could not.

Comment: Yes then you can use the "data" variable to iterate over each tweet and not over each line. It will be much easier to iterate over "objects" than to iterate over lines. If you can post your JSON structure it might give a better idea how you can do what you want.

Comment: Hi Radiv (sorry i could not know to get structute as you mention ) i have to use pprint to dump on screen and write down what i believe a strucutre {u'contributors':None,
u'coordinates':None,
u'created_at' u'Mon Oct29 23:2 +0000 2012
u’entities':{ u'hashtags':[{ u'indices’: [0,6], u'text’ : u'Sandy’}],
            u'urls':[{ u'display_url..


….
u'text’: u'# Sandy   

…………..

},

 {u'contributors':None,

…
}

Comment: Looks like you should read a bit more about JSON and how to work with it from python first. Try http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: i could send you a screen shoot by e mail since i need to extract the content but could not get clear how after reading twitter dev

Comment: Dear Radi, thank for your link, i try it as following:                  import  json
 f = file('data.json','r')
 lines = f.readlines()
 for line in lines:
    tweet = json.loads(line)

tweets =[]
 for line in lines:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    tweets.append(tweet[1]['text'])
result 
 tweets
\U0001f602\U0001f602 RT @AlicenCUCCiland: Sandy said she gone show us some re
shit ...*flips car* *flips house* *flips bang*']

Comment: Please check my updated answer and try it like this, you're still iterating over file lines which is not the way to deal with JSON.

Comment: Thanks so much. it works. Just want to say thanks for your spending time with me. Just wonder what does it mean, line[0] in  tweets_json = json.loads(lines[0]).

Comment: After you read the file with readlines() you get a list with one string, so lines[0] takes that string and passes it to json.loads() to convert it to a dictionary. Also if this works could you please accept the answer? Thanks